# How to run highfrequency package in R?

Tags: r

I want to apply `aggregatePrice` in highfrequency() package in R:
This is my data:

```
str(df_missing)
tibble [25,170 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Time : chr [1:25170] "2018-02-21 09:00:00" "2018-02-21 09:07:38" "2018-02-21 09:09:10" "2018-02-21 09:09:10" ...
 $ Price: num [1:25170] 122 122 122 122 122 ...
head(df_missing)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Time                Price
  <chr>               <dbl>
1 2018-02-21 09:00:00  122.
2 2018-02-21 09:07:38  122.
3 2018-02-21 09:09:10  122.
4 2018-02-21 09:09:10  122.
5 2018-02-21 09:09:21  122.
6 2018-02-21 09:13:16  122.
```

I tried using this coding:

```
aggregatePrice(df_missing$Price,alignBy = "minutes", alignPeriod = 30)
```

because I want to make 5 minutes aggregate data: but the ouput like this:

> Error in aggregatePrice(df_missing$Price, alignBy = "minutes", alignPeriod = 30) :
> Input has to be data.table or xts.

anyone who familiar with this fuction can help me

Comment: You data has to be `data.table` or `xts` instead of `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_missing) |> setnames('Time', 'DT')
aggregatePrice(df_missing, alignBy = 'minutes', alignPeriod = 30)
```

This fails given your example because there's not enough data. However, the example below (with more data), succeeds.

```
df_missing <- data.table(DT=seq(as.POSIXct('2018-02-21 09:00:00'), len=100, by='13 min'))
df_missing[, Price:=rgamma(100, shape=10, scale=10)]
aggregatePrice(df_missing, alignBy = 'minutes', alignPeriod = 30)
```

Comment: Hi Mr jlhoward its works, thanks

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks its work!,and want to know about this function df_missing[, Price:=rgamma(100, shape=10, scale=10)]

Comment: Sir i want to know why u choose shape =10 and scale=10 and N = 100, thank you

Comment: I was just tying to create a minimal reproducible example.  `rgamma(n, shape, scale)` generates a random sample from the gamma distribution. Type `?rgamma` in the console window for details. I chose gamma because we're talking about prices (which are > 0) and gamma has support on (0, Inf). `n` is just the sample size, and `shape` and `scale` are parameters of the distribution. For gamma, `E(X) = shape * scale`. So, random prices > 0 with mean 100. Nothing more sophisticated than that.